# Does time flows differently now compared to moments after big bang?

Tags: photons, speed-of-light, time, big-bang

Has time been flowing at a steady pace ever since big bang or it was very different compared to the early universe say before photon epoch? I suspect time ticks at the same rate throughout the timeline since the big bang occurs because speed of light is a constant but that's just my hunch.

Comment: Asking how quickly time is flowing is not meaningful without a reference. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/675369/is-universe-expansion-means-that-speed-of-time-flow-is-increasing for comments.